# How to use AWS-RunRemoteScript on AWS CLI?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cli

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to use the AWS CLI on Windows to pull a PowerShell script off of a GitHub repo and onto an AWS EC2 instance, then run that script on the instance.

**What I've tried**

I know the escaped double quotes (\") are valid, as I've tried without them to no avail. I've also tried putting the JSON part following --parameters in a separate file and loading that file into the command, but it complained about formatting in that case.

I've tried the command in both PowerShell and the Windows CMD (the two differ in syntax, namely with double quotes). I've included both variations below.

Using the AWS EC2 Console, I can get all of this to work using the graphical interface. The key now is getting it to also work using the command line.

**Here's the command for PowerShell:**

`aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunRemoteScript" --document-version "1" --targets "Key=instanceids,Values=<INSTANCE-ID>" --parameters '{\"sourceType\":[\"GitHub\"],\"sourceInfo\":{\"owner\":\"<USERNAME>\",\"repository\":\"Projects\",\"path\":\"test_script.ps1\"},\"commandLine\":[\".\\test_script.ps1\"],\"workingDirectory\":[""],\"executionTimeout\":[\"3600\"]}' --timeout-seconds 600 --max-concurrency "50" --max-errors "0" --region us-east-2`

The problem seems to be coming from the --parameters param and the JSON following it.

**Here's the command for Git Bash (which actually works):**

`aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunRemoteScript" --document-version "1" --targets "Key=instanceids,Values=<INSTANCE-ID>" --parameters '{"sourceType":["GitHub"],"sourceInfo":["{\"owner\": \"<USERNAME>\", \"repository\": \"Projects\", \"path\": \"test_script.ps1\"}"],"commandLine":[".\\test_script.ps1"],"workingDirectory":[""],"executionTimeout":["3600"]}' --timeout-seconds 600 --max-concurrency "50" --max-errors "0" --region us-east-2`

**Here's the resulting error:**

> `Parameter validation failed: Invalid type for parameter Parameters.sourceInfo, value: OrderedDict([('owner', '<USERNAME>'), ('repository', 'Projects'), ('path', 'test_script.ps1')]), type: <class 'collections.OrderedDict'>, valid types: <class 'list'>, <class 'tuple'>`

---

**How do I specify these parameters in the appropriate format?**

Answer (score 1):

There is some JSON parsing issue from PowerShell or from CMD.exe, the same command works just fine from Linux Shell:

```
aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunRemoteScript" --document-version "1" --targets "Key=instanceids,Values=mi-012dcb3ecea45b678" --parameters '{"sourceType":["GitHub"],"sourceInfo":[" {\n \"owner\":\"<user>\",\n \"repository\":\"<my-repo>\",\n \"path\":\"get-param.ps1\",\n \"getOptions\":\"branch:master\",\n \"tokenInfo\":\"{{ssm-secure:<my-token>}}\"\n }"],"commandLine":["get-param.ps1"],"workingDirectory":[""],"executionTimeout":["3600"]}' --timeout-seconds 600 --max-concurrency "50" --max-errors "0" --region eu-west-1
```

I actually had opened this issue with awscli team, they confirmed this type of parsing limitations with Windows, check: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4212#issuecomment-507378423

So, if you use the same approach, to use the parameters in a json file, you can do it as below:

Create param.json file with below content:

```
{
    "sourceType": [
        "GitHub"
    ],
    "sourceInfo": [
        " {\n \"owner\":\"<user>\",\n \"repository\":\"<repo>\",\n \"path\":\"get-param.ps1\",\n \"getOptions\":\"branch:master\",\n \"tokenInfo\":\"{{ssm-secure:<token>}}\"\n }"
    ],
    "commandLine": [
        "get-param.ps1"
    ],
    "workingDirectory": [
        ""
    ],
    "executionTimeout": [
        "3600"
    ]
}
```

Then you should be able to run the command as below:

```
aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunRemoteScript" --document-version "1" --targets "Key=instanceids,Values=mi-012dcb3ecea45b678" --parameters file://param.json --timeout-seconds 600 --max-concurrency "50" --max-errors "0" --region eu-west-1
```

This will work from cmd.exe as well as from PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

You can always go nuts (as I did) and double escape the content.
The parameters' value should be a string that represents a json that contains a property that is a collection of strings that represent a json.

I'm serious here.

`aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunRemoteScript" --document-version "1" --targets "Key=instanceids,Values=<INSTANCE-ID>" --parameters '{\"sourceType\":[\"GitHub\"],\"sourceInfo\":[\"{\\\"owner\\\":\\\"<USERNAME>\\\",\\\"repository\\\":\\\"Projects\\\"}\"],\"commandLine\":[\".\\test_script.ps1\"],\"workingDirectory\":[""],\"executionTimeout\":[\"3600\"]}' --timeout-seconds 600 --max-concurrency "50" --max-errors "0" --region us-east-2`

So the whole trick here is to create the escaping backslash by putting the escaped backslash `\\` before the already escaped quote `\"` in the right places.

Answer (score 0):

With PowerShell [Send-SSMCommand cmdlet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Send-SSMCommand.html) I found it easiest to [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7) the command and not worry about the encapsulation and escaping (as much)

```bsh
$mySSMCommand = @{
  ProfileName = 'default'
  DocumentName = 'DocumentName'
  Target = @{Key='InstanceIds'
  Values=@('i-ABCDEFG')}
  Parameter = @{
    sourceType='S3'
    sourceInfo='{"path": "https://bucketbucketbucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/somescript.ps1"}'
    commandLine='somescript.ps1 -MyParam "value"'
  }
}

Send-SSMCommand @mySSMCommand
```